# How to make a plot filled from x=-1 to x=1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code, plots a normal distribution curve:

```
import scipy as sp, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

x = np.arange(-6, 6, 0.1)

distrib_1 = norm(0, 1) 
y_distrib_1 = distrib_1.pdf(x)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8)) 

axes = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

axes.plot(x, y_distrib_1, color='red', linewidth=2, label=r'Normal distribution: $\mu = 0, \sigma = 1$')

axes.set_xlabel('x')
axes.set_ylabel('P(x)')
axes.set_title('The Normal Distribution')
axes.grid(True)
axes.legend(loc=2);
plt.show()
```

Now I want to fill the range between x=-1 and x=1.  What I tried to do is `axes.fill_between(x, y_distrib_1, 0, where = -1<x<1)` but then I get the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` at that line.

I tried `axes.fill_between(x, y_distrib_1, 0, where = (-1<x and x<1), color='red')` and it also didn't work.

What I can do is:

```
p = [(True if -1<val and val<1 else False) for val in x]
axes.fill_between(x, y_distrib_1, 0, where = p)
```

that works, but this code feels quite ugly.

What to do? I didn't find any similar example in the matplotlib documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, this will work:
`axes.fill_between(x, y_distrib_1, 0, where = (-1<x) & (x<1))`

Answer (score -1):

It should be something like

```
fill_between(y_distrib_1, 0, where = (-1<x&&x<1)).
```

Remember, most languages cannot parse things like `-1<x<1`. Even though that is a perfectly sound mathematical idea, the way most code sees it is like this:

```
is -1 < x? Yes? Ok, the statement -1 < x is now TRUE.
is TRUE<1? TRUE in python is 1, so is 1<1, no, FALSE.
```

The code won't test x against both  -1 and 1, you have to break it up and put an "and" (&&) in.

Edit: looking at the actual way to use fill_between, it looks like you should do this

```
fill_between(y_distrib_1,-1, 1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I still get the same error (using `and` instead of `&&`).

Comment: I looked up how fill_between works, try my edit out.

Comment: One more try, I was on the wrong axis I think: fill_between(y_distrib_1,-1, 1)